# Gradle: Add dependency from Java to Native compilation

Tags: java, c, gradle, java-native-interface

I try to setup gradle for a proper JNI compilation, so I need to build first a shared library (with the c plugin), and then compile and test the java code (which consumes the library).

Here a sample of the build.gradle, related to the native compilation:

```
model {
    components {
        yli(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                c {
                    source {
                        srcDir 'src/main/c'
                        include "Yli.c"
                        commonFolders.each {
                            include "$it/**/*.c"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            buildTypes {
                release
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to tell gradle that the compileJava should wait for the build of the NativeLibrarySpec?

**Edit**: When I try to add

```
compileJava.dependsOn(yliSharedLibrary)
```

I have the following error during gradle build:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'yli'.
> Could not get unknown property 'sharedLibrary' for root project 'yli' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Note: I used the command 'gradle tasks' in order to found the name of the task: 'yliSharedLibrary'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this and discovered that you can access the tasks created by the [software model](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/software_model.html) within closures. For example, if you want to depend on one of the native tasks, you can do so with:

```
compileJava.dependsOn { yliNativeCompileTask }
```

Of course, if you want the Java task to come after the native one, but not force an actual dependency between them, you can use `mustRunAfter()`:

```
compileJava.mustRunAfter { yliNativeCompileTask }
```

This syntax also works for declared inputs and outputs:

```
compileJava.inputs.files { yliNativeCompileTask }
```

Note that if you tie the inputs of a task to the outputs of another task, you don't have to explicitly declare a `dependsOn`. Gradle infers the task dependency.

**Disclaimer** I don't know if this is the correct way to do this, or how far you can take this approach.

One final thing: the old native software model is being replaced by a [new set of native plugins](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-the-new-cpp-plugins) based on Gradle's original model. It should be much easier to integrate Java projects with these new plugins, but you may want to wait until the plugins have been fully fleshed out before attempting a migration.